# Best way to make your own custom UI widget complete with js,css and html reusable?

Tags: html, widget

I have a complex html element that has some css and associated js with it. It is a combination of a html5 slider, multiple labels and text box. The problem is that it is likely to be used up at a lot of places. Re-writing the html, css, js is not the best way to make it re-usable. Here are my requirements

- Easily insertable (just like dojo or jquery widgets)
- Maintainable (Exactly the reason why I dont want my css/html/js to be sprinkled all over, instead I want something more compact)
- Options (This Ui element has plenty of configuration options that enable/disable/hide/show individual html elements within my complex UI, I need a way for a developer to mention those as well)

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The W3C standard for this sort of thing will likely be [Web Components](http://www.w3.org/TR/components-intro/), though the spec is not finalized and so far [only Chrome has an implementation](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/) ([relevant Firefox request](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=811542)).  There was a talk on [Web Components and Shadow DOM (video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=fqULJBBEVQE) at the recent Google I/O.  The [X-Tag custom elements polylib](http://www.x-tags.org/) will allow you to start experimenting with Web Components now.

If you need to support versions of IE prior to 9 you're stuck with building things in a similar way to the Dojo and jQuery UI widgets you mention.

Comment: This answer is inaccurate on a few points - here are the Web Components features we are actively implementing in Gecko: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=811542 - they should start landing over the next few weeks/months.

Comment: Additionally, Mozilla was in on the specs early in the game and has been driving their evolution (I was in the room for many of the meetings, and a primary contributor for Mozilla). We also developed X-Tag (http://www.x-tags.org/), a Web Components sugar library that shares the same polyfill layer Google uses in Polymer

Comment: @csuwldcat Thanks for the link to the correct bugzilla bug, I'll add a link to the X-tags project